# Lebensmittel aus Teig

Tags: single-word-request, terminology

Bis vor kurzem hatte ich angenommen, dass "Teigwaren" ein Oberbegriff sei für alle Lebensmittel, die aus Teig hergestellt werden, musste aber bei Recherche feststellen, dass dem anscheinend nicht so ist, sondern dass Teigwaren sich nur auf Pasta (umgangssprachlich auch - nicht ganz korrekt - Nudeln) bezieht und beispielsweise Brot nicht zu den Teigwaren zählt. Brot, Kuchen und Kekse - obwohl eindeutig auch aus Teig hergestellt - werden als "Backwaren" bezeichnet, was Pasta definitiv ausschließt.

Daher meine Frage: Gibt es einen Oberbegriff, der alle diese Lebensmittel einschließt? Wobei Kuchen/Kekse hier eher der Vollständigkeit halber aufgeführt sind, konkret geht es mir um einen Oberbegriff, der sowohl Pasta als auch Brot umfasst.
(Theoretisch ginge noch "Getreideprodukte", aber der Begriff ist mir ein wenig zu unspezifisch und auch etwas zu sperrig).

Comment: Teigwaren sind nicht nur Pasta. Teig- unterscheiden sich von Backwaren durch die Zubereitung. Teigwaren werden in kochendem Wasser gegart, Backwaren wenig überraschend gebacken.

Comment: Ich vermute mal, Grundnahrungsmittel dürfte dir ach zu unspezifisch sein.

Comment: @infinitezero Da Grundnahrungsmittel noch erheblich weiter gefasst ist als Getreideprodukt, lautet die Antwort darauf ganz überraschenderweise "ja" :-)

Comment: "Pasta (umgangssprachlich auch - nicht ganz korrekt - Nudeln)" Wie meinst du das? Spannend ist der Wikipediaartikel zu Teigwaren https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teigwaren. Da stehen auch die verschiedenen Definitionen

Comment: Nichts gegen die Frage, sie ist interessant. Aber ich fange an zu grübeln, ob das nicht eigentlich eine Fachterminologiefrage ist. Wenn solche Fragen hier möglich sind, könnte man dann nicht hier auch fragen, ob Amylmetabolonpolyhexametase ein zulässiges Hyperonym ist für Amylmetabolon-2-3-hexametase und Amylmetabolon-2-4-hexametase. Oder allgemeiner: Sind Fragen nach Nomenklaturen in Fachsprachen bestimmter Industriezweige wirklich Fragen zu Regeln der deutschen Sprache?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich hatte kurz überlegt, den Tag Fachterminologie zu verwenden, mich dann aber dagegen entschieden. Sowohl Teigwaren als auch Getreideprodukte sind ja durchaus alltagstaugliche Begriffe, was auf Deine Beispiele nicht mehr so wirklich zutrifft ;-)

Comment: Auch wenn vielleicht mehr Leute was unter Teigwaren verstehen als unter Amylmetabolonpolyhexametase, bin ich mir nicht sicher ob "Teigwaren" ein alltagstauglicher Begriff ist. Auch wenn einige Leute sich bemühen eine übertrieben und unpassend gehobene Sprache zu verwenden, kann ich es nicht so richtig glauben, dass Otto Normalkoch (oder Erika Normalköchin) von Teigwaren sprechen, wenn sie Nudeln kochen.

Comment: @jarnbjo, also in meiner Familie wird das normal verwendet. "Was willst du dazu essen? Reis, Kartoffeln oder Teigwaren und wenn ja, welche (Nudeln, Gnocci, Schupfnudeln, Spätzle, Knödel...)?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auch wenn der Begriff "Getreideprodukte" in der Frage als eher ungeeignet eingestuft wurde, scheint es doch in diese Richtung zu gehen.

Das Deutsche Lebensmittelbuch der [Deutschen Lebensmittelbuch-Kommission](http://deutsche-lebensmittelbuch-kommission.de/)  kennt sieben verschiedene Produktgruppen. Der Fachausschuss 4 der Kommission kümmert sich dabei um die Produktgruppe "Getreideerzeugnisse, Kartoffelerzeugnisse, Ölsamenerzeugnisse". Hierbei gibt es je ein Kapitel "Kartoffelerzeugnisse" und "Ölsamen", so dass die restlichen drei Kapitel "Brot und Kleingebäck", "Feine Backwaren" und "Teigwaren" wohl tatsächlich unter dem Oberbegriff

> Getreideerzeugnisse

zusammengefasst werden.

Comment: hm, na gut - wenn in den nächsten Stunden/Tagen nicht noch was besseres kommt, werde ich mich wohl damit begnügen müssen.

Comment: Unter „Getreideerzeugnis“ würde ich auch Hafermilch verstehen.

Comment: @lejonet, aber Hafermilch gehört offiziell zur Gruppe  "Vegane und vegetarische Lebensmittel mit Ähnlichkeit zu Lebensmitteln tierischen Ursprungs" ;)